# How to restore the Microsoft extension user data to another pc?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have my OKX ID and password, but did not save the seed phrase. I have the old back up with me from the directory: The source code is at C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions{{id}}!.

But this file seems cannot be moved from one pc to another. Is it possible to restore it back to another pc with some decode / in developer mode? Thanks.

I have tried to copy from the back up to another computer but copy and trying to paste it back in the same source folder, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean restore the same extension on another machine, you can refer to the following methods:

Is the extension installed from online extension store? If so, you can login Edge profile with the same account on the two machines and make sure sync of extension is turned on. Then the installed extension will be synced to the other machine.

[image]

For the method you have tried, I think it also make sense. After you paste the folder, you need to open **Developer mode** in this page *edge://extensions/* in Edge, then click **Load unpacked** to load the extension folder. Please note that when you choose the folder when load unpacked, you need to select to the level where `manifest.json` file exists. Then the extension will show up on the machine.

[image]

If you mean restore some kind of password information stored in the extension to another machine, it might be impossible. This kind of encrypted information cannot be copied and pasted directly between different machines due to security reasons.

Comment: Hi Yu Zhou, thanks for such a quick response. Yes i am actually looking to restore some kind of ID information stored. I do have the password, but there is a default ID that is being saved. Everytime when i open the old PC, this extension will automatically pull out based on my default ID, i do remember my password. But the ID is what i need to restore.  It is a OKX crypto ID.

Comment: Have you tried the two methods in my answer? Can they restore the ID on the other machine?